# Serving index.html to the Google bot with ?_escaped_fragment_=

Tags: c, nginx, url-rewriting, googlebot

I have a very Javascript heavy application which I'd like to get indexed. I have a directory of snapshots on my website which can be served to the Google bot. These are under `mysite.com/snapshots/`.

I'm using the following rewrite rule to serve the snapshot to the Google bot:

```
location / {
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=") {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /snapshots/$1.html break;
    }
}
```

This works for all of my snapshots except the home page. The problem is, the homepage gets saved as `mysite.com/snapshots/index.html`. When the Google bot requests `mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=`, nginx tried to serve `/snapshots/.html` and obviously the request 404's.

I need to adapt the rewrite rule to serve up index.html when the document root is requested.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above your rewrite line add:

```
rewrite ^/$ /index.html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your server configuration, no matter where, just within `server{}`.

```
location ^= index\.html$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

This checks if there requested URL ends with `index.html`. If this doesn't do the trick, I'd need full URLs as the Google bot requests them.